# Does mocha for Node.js scripts test have a nice html output that Mocha for browser has?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

Is there any mocha reporter extension or simply way of generating a nice looking html mocha test result like http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/example/tests.html does?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, that one is called "spec" and it's available via `--reporter spec`

Answer (score 0):

It is the **doc** reporter.

```
--reporter doc
```

See [Mocha Reporters](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/tree/master/lib/reporters) for details on available reporters.

Answer (score 0):

The doc reporter generates documentation for your test code itself, it does not create nice html results of the output from your test runs.